# how to calculate total salary of an employee with employee data in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, aggregate-functions

I am working with laravel 5.1 and have two tables.

1. employees
2. wages

Structure:

```
employees

id|name|city

1 |doe |TX

2 |John|Phx


wages

id|employee_id|wages

1 |1                 |200
2 |1                 |100
3 |1                 |300
4 |2                 |500
5 |1                 |200
6 |2                 |800
7 |1                 |200
8 |2                 |600
9 |1                 |200
```

So as per my question i wanted to fetch list of employees including sum of wages for all employees and want to list on my blade in a tabular form like emp name| city|total wages etc. using laravels eloquent from employees model.

I have tried accessors & mutators of laravel but they didn't work?
If you want i can share my code as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$employees = DB::table('wages')          
             ->join('employees', 'employees.id', '=', 'wages.employee_id')
             ->select('employee.name as name', 'employee.city as city', DB::raw('SUM(wages.wages) as total_wages'))
             ->groupBy('employee_id')
             ->get();
```

and in your view:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>City</th>
         <th>Wage</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      @foreach ($employees as $employee)
         <tr>
            <td>{{ $employee->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $employee->city }}</td>
            <td>{{ $employee->total_wages }}</td>
         </tr>
      @endforeach
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Check if it helps you...

Comment: This can help but i have to also show employees records on view also. So need to hit the query from employee model.                                                                               Some thing like that : Employee::all();

Comment: I think this will work. But as i got i think i missed some part of my question so i edited again.

Comment: Basically, do you want to show a table containing the name of employee, his city, and the sum of his wages? Is this what you want?

Comment: How can i add realtions ?

Comment: I want to do with relationships. Like Accessors and Mutators in Laravel. No custom query.

Comment: Try to use `addSelect` method to add `DB::raw('SUM(wages.wages) as total_wages')`

Answer (score 0):

> here is the sql query to get the sum of each employ with multiple record

```
SELECT b.id,employ_name, SUM(wages) FROM test.wages as a LEFT JOIN test.employees as b on a.employ_id=b.id GROUP BY a.employ_id
```

> where test=database name; wages & employees are table name
>
> if you need employ city you can add on employ table and add b.employ_city before or after employ_name in query and separate them by ','. and i think this query help to give knowledge about extracting information from table. and you can convert to laravel accepted format. because i haven't knowledge of laravel

Comment: This is sql. I wanted to do this in as per laravel standards

Comment: You can try this one                                            $employ_detail=DB::table('wages')
        ->leftJoin('employees', 'wages.employ_id', '=', 'employees.employ_id')->groupBy('wages.employ_id')
        ->select('wages.id', 'employees.name', 'employees.city', DB::raw('SUM(wages.wages) as total_wages'))
        ->get();